# how to declare variables(local, user defined) in mysql stored-procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I'm creating stored procedure in mysql. I declare some variables, but occur error. I don't know problem.

Error is

> "Incorrect synstax near 'Declare'".

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_APPDOCLISTSIGNBOXREAD_GET(
P_SESSIONID         VARCHAR(256),
P_EMPID             VARCHAR(20),
P_FORMSEQ           VARCHAR(5)
)
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    DECLARE V_DRAFTDEPT  VARCHAR(20); -- ***This line is error.***
    DECLARE V_ADMINCOUNT INT;

    SET @V_STRSQL = '';         -- Dynamic query variable
    SET @V_STRWHERE = '';       -- Dynamic query variable   
    SET @V_STRPARAM = '';       -- Dynamic query variable

    SET V_DRAFTDEPT = '';
    SET V_ADMINCOUNT = 0;

    SELECT DEPTCODE INTO V_DRAFTDEPT
      FROM TBEMPLOYEE
     WHERE EMPID = P_EMPID;
END
```

Comment: Move `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` after the `DECLARE`s.

Comment: Thank you for answer!!^^ Good day!

Answer (score 1):

The *order* of statements with a MySQL program is pretty specific.

The `DECLARE` statements have to come first.

And there's an order for the `DECLARE` statements too. For example, any `DECLARE ... HANDLER` statements must come after variable declarations.

---

If it wasn't clear... MySQL is returning an error for the `DECLARE` statement because it's not valid following a `SET` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Good day ^^